# React rendering issue

Tags: html, reactjs, dom, webstorm

I am new to react environment, I have tried it in WebStorm. The DOM is completely blank. I have attached following files as html and js files.

This is the index.html

```html
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
<div id="root"></div>
<script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

The script.js is

```
import React from "react"
import ReactDOM from "react-dom"

// JSX
ReactDOM.render(<div><h1>Hello world!</h1><p>This is a paragraph</p></div>, document.getElementById("root"))
```

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't try to use React like this, I think.
Please take a look at your code lines I wrote in codepen.

`https://codepen.io/web-sudo/pen/qBNJpRb`

It works. Why? Because it has it's own react development environment in codepen modules.
But in the above code, as you can see you wrote `import React from "react"`.
Meaning, you wanted `react` module in script.js. But where is the `react` module?
You didn't have it.

So you need to include `react` and `react-dom` modules inside of your development environment.
Please focus on the below example.

`https://www.w3schools.com/react/showreact.asp?filename=demo2_react_test`

Here you can see such comments :
/*
The examples in this tutorial are created using the
create-react-app. Install the create-react-app,
and you will be able to run the same examples on your computer.

In this example we create a component called 'Test'.
The component is rendered in a container called 'root'.
Click the 'index.html' tab to see the container.
*/

Overall, you do need to follow the guides in this link.

`https://reactjs.org/docs/create-a-new-react-app.html`

Answer (score 1):

Follow these steps to create your project in React.

1. `npx create-react-app hello-world`
2. `cd hello-world`
3. Change the contents of `App.js` to the following

```
import "./App.css";

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello World!</h1>
      <p>This is a paragraph</p>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

4. `yarn start` or `npm start`

You should see this in the browser

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You are not rendering a react component. Try [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/) to create a simple react app with the official template.